# In Express.js, is there a route equivalent to res.locals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

When using Express.js/Jade, it's possible to add a function (or a variable) to res.locals and then use said function in a Jade-view like below.

In Express middleware:

```
res.locals.myUtilFunction = function(){ return 'Hello' };
```

In Jade:

```
- console.log(myUtilFunction());
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar inside of an Express route function? Like:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    myUtilFunction(); //Instead of having to do res.locals.myUtilFunction() each time...
}
```

I've searched high and low for an answer but couldn't find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does that function access to req or res? If not you can use declare as global function or module function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can bind it to global although I would probably avoid making a habbit out of this

app.js

```
global.myFunction = function (text){ 
  console.log(text);
}
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
....
```

routes/index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  myFunction('test');
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

Comment: I'd have to agree, binding to global isn't ideal... However, that seems to be the only way of achieving this. I was just hoping that there'd be some sort of magic JS-esque solution to this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom function to bind whatever you want to the request and response objects.
This way you don't have to bind to the global scope.

Just put this in your initialization code before loading the router.

```
app.use function(req, res, next) {
    req.loadWhatever = function() { ... };

    return next();
}
```

In your routing method, you can then access `req.loadWhatever`.

Comment: Keeping in mind my comment on @Brendan's answer, your solution seems to be a good compromise. Thanks (I'd upvote your answer but my rep isn't good enough yet).

Comment: Thank you. :) Glad to hear I could help!